# How to set a symbol indirectly?

Tags: symbols, assignment, subscript

I have a symbol, say x, whose calculated value is a 2nd symbol. How can I set the 2nd symbol to a given value? For example, say the value of x is one of the symbols a, b, or c. If it is a, I want to set a = 10. If it is b, I want to set b = 10. Ditto for c. But, I can use a, b, or c only if I can extract it from x. I want to do something like

```
x=a
%=10
Out= a=10
```

To complicate this just a bit, my 2nd "symbols" actually are subscripts, like Subscript[a,1], Subscript[a,1,2], Subscript[a,1,3,4]. I found a partial solution.

```
x=Subscript[a,3];
Subscript[x[[1]],x[[2]]=10;
Subscript[a,3]
Out(1)= 10
```

But how do I do this if a has n subscripts? How do I write something like

```
x=Subscript[a,3,4,2, ..., 5];
Subscript[a,x[[2]], ... , x[[n]]]=10
```

Comment: `Hold[x = 10] /. OwnValues[x] // ReleaseHold`? -- BTW, I avoid subscripts for variables, and most questions about them. But then I've only been using *Mathematica* for a couple of decades or so. Still, `OwnValues` might work with them, if `x` is a regular symbol.  Otherwise, maybe `DownValues` will work.

Comment: I just discovered a partial solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the hold on the left hand side of an assignment with `Evaluate`.

```
x=a
```

> ```
> a
> ```

```
Evaluate[x]=10
```

> ```
> 10
> ```

```
a
```

> ```
> 10
> ```

```
x = Subscript[b, 1]
```

> ```
> Subscript[b, 1]
> ```

```
Evaluate[x] = 2
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

```
Subscript[b, 1]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

But why?

Comment: Why? Because it sounds like the OP wants reference-type variable passing...

Comment: Thank you, Mark. This seems to do the trick. I searched for "Release" in the Documentation Center and it says that Release has been superseded by Evaluate and ReleaseHold. I tried them and Evaluate seems to work the same way but not ReleaseHold.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. I'm an old timer, so I still use `Release`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Note that this will not work again. Once `a` is set to a number, `x` then evaluates to a number, as does `x=a`.

Comment: oops. I need "a" to work over and over. I was just noticing it didn't work the 2nd time in my code. Is there a work-around? Can I clear or reset a?

Comment: Sure. You can `a=.`. However I am still wondering why you are doing this. You may want to ask a new question about what you are actually trying to do. There is probably a better approach for that than this.

Comment: I'm sure you are right that there is an easier way and I might yet ask the larger question separately. However, I have already built an extensive module that successfully computes a complicated non-symmetric multiplication of two generic objects (n-dimensional Clifs), and it handles subscripts just fine. I would hate to abandon subscripts now and lose all that. This last step is just to take a user's input and match it to the generic objects. I am a Mathematica newbie and I am learning the language as I do this.

Comment: @matrixbud I thought of Mark's solution, but rejected it because you can only set `a` once: `Clear[x, a]; x = a; Evaluate[x] = 10; Evaluate[x] = 20;`...